Google Cloud Storage Image Loading Issue 403 Error with v3 Signer API Authentication
I'm new to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). I've been trying to setup my personal blog website. This website will be using images as well. For hosting images, I use GCS bucket with a load balancer with CDN caching.
When I try to load any blog post with images, the images from GCS gives 403 forbidden error when v3/signer API fails to authenticate. I want to make sure that user visiting my website without any Google login should be able to view images on my blog post.
Recently I did following with my GCS bucket:

Added CORS policy.

[
    {
        "origin": ["https://link-to-my-blogpost.com"],
        "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
        "method": ["GET"],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]


Updated bucket permissions (access control) to fine-grained object level ACLs. Earlier it was set to uniform.

After this I ran a command to update ACL of bucket:
gsutil -m acl -r set public-read gs://my-bucket-name 


Public access is subject to object ACLs.


For reference attaching screenshot of the error:

I'm still facing 403 forbidden error due to which images are not getting loaded on my website. It would be a great help if anyone can help me figure out what I'm missing. Thanks!

Have you checked if you have the required roles based on this documentation?
